# Inserting an entry in Ruby hash at specific position

Tags: ruby

Given a hash with, say, a nested hash in it:

```
hash = {"some_key" => "value",
        "nested" => {"key1" => "val1", 
                     "key2" => "val2"}}
```

and a path to a key in String format:

```
path = "nested.key2"
```

How can I add a new key-value pair **before** the key2 entry?
So, expected output should be something like this:

```
hash = {"some_key" => "value",
        "nested" => {"key1" => "val1",
                    "new_key" => "new_value"},
                    "key2" => "val2"}}
```

***EDITED***

My goal is to add a kind of label before some key in order to dump hash as Yaml text and post process the text to replace added key/value with Yaml comment. AFAIK, there is no other way to add comment before specific key in YAML programmatically.

Comment: @crible: How exactly is the path specification format defined? It lists `some_key` and then `nested`too? Confusing.

Comment: I think `path = "some_key.nested.key2"` would be `path = "nested.key2"`. confirm please.

Comment: @undur_gongor: yes, it defines the path like in a tree. So, this is a full path from root node to the child.

Comment: @OMG: You are correct.

Comment: I update the description (fix key path).

Comment: @undur_gongor: that's implementation detail. Hash in general is unordered structure.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: No, it is not. It is a documented feature of a hash in Ruby. And it was introduced because it is meant to be used.

Comment: @undur_gongor: but it was not meant to be abused. Which is what OP is trying to do, IMHO. I still stand my ground: if you need order, use arrays.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I agree that the intention of the OP is abuse. But "if you need order, use arrays"? No. Why do hashes maintain their order, then? Maybe "If you need to re-order, use arrays."

Comment: @undur_gongor my reasoning is simple: are they ordered universally, in all languages? I doubt that. Arrays, on the other hand, are ordered everywhere. That's their essence. Essence of a hash is the mapping (key to value). Insertion time ordering is just a nice thing to have. If you grow to heavily rely on it and then move to a language where hashes are not ordered, you'll have hard time. Heck, who knows that even in ruby they will stay ordered? Arrays, on the other hand, will maintain this property, I guarantee it. :)

Comment: @undur_gongor When I think about it, I can't name a single use case, where I would rely on order of hash key/value pairs. Maybe I'm missing something. How would *you* use it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Read some structured data in and dump it to test your program -> simple comparison for free. Matz decided it is worth implementing, so it's meant to be used/relied on in Ruby: http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/12552.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is easiest by using the Hash's array representation:

```
subhash   = hash['nested'].to_a
insert_at = subhash.index(subhash.assoc('key2'))
hash['nested'] = Hash[subhash.insert(insert_at, ['new_key', 'new_value'])]
```

It could be wrapped into a function:

```
class Hash
  def insert_before(key, kvpair)
    arr = to_a
    pos = arr.index(arr.assoc(key))
    if pos
      arr.insert(pos, kvpair)
    else
      arr << kvpair
    end
    replace Hash[arr]
  end
end

hash['nested'].insert_before('key2', ['new_key', 'new_value'])

p hash # {"some_key"=>"value", "nested"=>{"key1"=>"val1", "new_key"=>"new_value", "key2"=>"val2"}}
```

Comment: thanks, that is really simple and elegant solution for inserting an entry in a hash.

Answer (score 2):

I often create YAML generators for large configurations for apps. For maintenance I need the fields sorted.

The solution I use when generating YAML in a sorted order, is to add the keys as necessary to get them in the right hash, or sub-hash. Then I create a new hash by sorting the key/value pairs and do `to_yaml` on it.

There's no point sorting a hash but sorting the temporary hash to be output prior to letting YAML have it does work and results in a more easily maintained file.

```
require 'yaml'

some_hash = {
    'z' => 1,
    'a' => 3
}

puts some_hash.to_yaml
```

Which outputs:

```
---
z: 1
a: 3
```

Sorting it prior to creating the YAML output:

```
puts Hash[some_hash.merge('x' => 2).sort_by{ |k, v| k }].to_yaml
```

Outputs:

```
---
a: 3
x: 2
z: 1
```

Instead of `puts`, use `File.write` or embed the line in a block passed to `File.open`.

---

Regarding comments in YAML files: YAML doesn't support adding comments programmatically to the emitted output. Comments are for humans, and the `#` isn't mappable to a Ruby variable or object. Think of it this way: If we start with this YAML in a file called `test.yaml`:

```
---
# string
a: 'fish'
# array
b: 
  - 1
  - 2
# hash
c: 
  d: 'foo'
  e: 'bar'
# integer
z: 1
```

And load it:

```
require 'pp'
require 'yaml'

obj = YAML.load_file('test.yaml')

pp obj
```

I get an `obj` looking like:

```
{"a"=>"fish", "b"=>[1, 2], "c"=>{"d"=>"foo", "e"=>"bar"}, "z"=>1}
```

There is no "comment" objects returned, and there are none that exist in Ruby that would fit into the hash, that exists in the YAML spec. We could arbitrarily cobble up a class that we call Comment, and try embedding it in the object as a key, but YAML wouldn't accept it as a comment, because the spec doesn't allow it. It would define it as a Ruby class and recreate it as that class, but it wouldn't be displayed as a `#` comment:

```
require 'yaml'

class Comment
  def initialize(some_text)
    @comment = "# #{some_text}"
  end
end

some_hash = {
  'a' => 1,
  Comment.new('foo') => 'bar',
  'z' => 'z'
}

puts some_hash.to_yaml
```

Outputting:

```
---
a: 1
? !ruby/object:Comment
  comment: ! '# foo'
: bar
z: z
```

When I've needed comments in my emitted YAML configurations, I manually tweak them to add them later. For what you want to do, rather than do any manual tweaking, I'd recommend using more mnemonic or unique variable names that you can scan for in your document. You could even put in dummy entries that don't provide to anything worthwhile except acting as a place holder:

```
require 'yaml'

some_hash = {
  'a' => 1,
  '__we_are_here__' => '',
  'b' => 2,
  '__we_are_now_here__' => '',
  'z' => 'z'
}

puts some_hash.to_yaml
```

Resulting in a YAML file like:

```
---
a: 1
__we_are_here__: ''
b: 2
__we_are_now_here__: ''
z: z
```

---

As far as inserting the key into the hash, I'd probably restructure my "key chain" a little, to show the path where I want to insert it, and the name of the new key. Again, I'd rely on sorting to make sure things were in the right order prior to saving the YAML:

```
require 'pp'

# this changes the incoming hash
def insert_embedded_hash_element(hash, key_path, new_value)

  keys = key_path.split('.')
  new_key = keys.pop

  sub_hash = hash
  keys.each do |k|
    sub_hash = sub_hash[k]
  end

  sub_hash[new_key] = new_value

end

# the sub-hash to insert into + new key name
insert_key = 'nested.key2'
insert_value = 'new_value'

hash = {
  "some_key" => "value",
  "nested" => {
    "key1" => "val1", 
    "key3" => "val2"
  }
}

insert_embedded_hash_element(hash, insert_key, insert_value)

pp hash
```

Resulting in:

```
{"some_key"=>"value",
 "nested"=>{"key1"=>"val1", "key3"=>"val2", "key2"=>"new_value"}}
```

Comment: It would be very interesting to see such an example.

Comment: don't know about such YAML possibility, thanks for provided example. It may be the solution, I'll check it.

Answer (score 2):

This is just as per the OP's need,but anytime can be modified as per the needs:

```
require 'yaml'

hash = {"some_key" => "value",
        "nested" => {"key1" => "val1", 
                     "key2" => "val2"}}

new_hash = %w(nested key2).inject(hash) do |h,i|
 next h[i] unless h.has_key? "key2"
 ind = h.to_a.index{|m| m[0] == i }
 Hash[h.to_a.insert(ind,["new_key","new_value"])]
end

hash["nested"] = new_hash # this part is to be taken care of for deep hash.
puts hash.to_yaml
```

*Output:*

```
some_key: value
nested:
  key1: val1
  new_key: new_value
  key2: val2
```

***UPDATE:***

I found the more efficient code,which will reduce overhead of taking care of the line `hash["nested"] = new_hash` in my previous code :

```
require 'yaml'

hash = {"some_key" => "value",
        "nested" => {"key1" => "val1", 
                     "key2" => "val2"}}

new_hash = %w(nested key2).inject(hash) do |h,i| # !> assigned but unused variable - new_hash
 next h[i] unless h.has_key? "key2"
 ind = h.to_a.index{|m| m[0] == i }
 h1 = Hash[h.to_a.insert(ind,["new_key","new_value"])]
 h.replace(h1)
end

hash
# => {"some_key"=>"value",
#     "nested"=>{"key1"=>"val1", "new_key"=>"new_value", "key2"=>"val2"}}

puts hash.to_yaml
# >> ---
# >> some_key: value
# >> nested:
# >>   key1: val1
# >>   new_key: new_value
# >>   key2: val2
```

Comment: Thanks for the great sample, it works perfectly! Will try to adopt to my code and comment you back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ruby provides this functionality for free.  You could do something like this, where you are creating an array of the existing hash keys, insert your new key into the array, then create a new hash with the newly ordered keys.

```
keys = original_hash.keys
keys.insert(new_key_position, new_key)

new_hash = {}
keys.each do |key|
  new_hash[key] = key == new_key ? new_value : original_hash[key]
end
```